# How can I Display a substring of the data

Tags: spring

I am a new at using Spring and I've spent hours searching over the net but I can't find a solid answer.

Using spring 2.0, I have a bean whose value is defined by a column from my database table. But now I only want it to display a portion of data in the column.

The original data looks like this: xxxxx.xxx
I only want the first part of the string (before the period) to appear on my web page.

I've looked into delimitedlinetokenizer and item processor but I don't feel like I'm on the right path. Any pointers would be much appreciated

This is how my bean is currently defined:

```
<bean id="date" class= "ColumnDefinitionImpl">
 <property name="column" ref="lastdate"/>
 <property name="path" ref="MY_Data_Col"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just split on `.` and show the first array entry?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you provide me with some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

As Dave pointed out, you can use just Java to get the desired value from original data, example:

```
String originalData = //logic to get the entire value from your DB
String desiredValue = originalData;  //If the original data does not contain "." then, the whole word is used. 
                                     //You can change it as you want
if(originalData != null){
  int index = originalData.indexOf(".");
  if(index != -1){
    desiredValue = originalData.substring(0,index);
  }

}
```

In this code, the `desiredValue` variable will contain the data you need
I hope this is what you want
EDIT
Based on your comment, I think you can put this logic into a setter of bean property:

```
private String dataWithoutDot;
//Getter here
//...
//Setter:
public void setDataWithoutDot(String originalData){
  if(originalData != null){
     int index = originalData.indexOf(".");
     if(index != -1){
       dataWithoutDot = originalData.substring(0,index);
     }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Based on your comment and since you don't have access to `ColumnDefinitionImpl` code modification.
I don't know if this is the best solution, but at least it should work:

```
<bean id="myFactoryBean"
  class="path.to.a.package.CustomDataFactory">
  <property name="path" ref="MY_Data_Col"/>
</bean>
```

You define a new factory class:

```
public class CustomDataFactory{
  private String path;
  //getter and setter
  //...
  //Our factory method:
  public String parseDataFromDB(){
    if(path != null){
      int index = path.indexOf(".");
      if(index != -1){
       return path.substring(0,index);
      }          
    }
    return path;
  }
}
```

And then, bach to your spring context file:

```
<bean id="date" class= "ColumnDefinitionImpl">
  <property name="column" ref="lastdate"/>
  <property name="path">
    <bean factory-bean="myFactoryBean" factory-method="parseDataFromDB">
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem is that I'm editing an xml file, and I don't think I can use java in it..?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to manipulate the data as a bean property, when I'm defining the bean...

Comment: can you give some more details ? I don't really know about your env, but I think if you include this same logic into the setter of the bean property that would work. See my edit

Comment: just include the logic I mentioned in my edit in the setter of `path` property and every thing should work fine

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the setter of the path property? is that the ref= portion?

Comment: nope. in your `ColumnDefinitionImpl` you should have a setter for `path`: `setPath` property like the one: `setDataWithoutDot`. don't you ? In that setter you include the same logic that I gave in my setter

Comment: so ? did you find out how to make it ?

Comment: It seems to be more complicated then that. I don't have access to the file that defines ColumnDefinitionImpl, so I'm not able to change the setter.

Comment: then, please see my edit again, I hope this is the solution you want